# Android development: Using intent syntax

Tags: android, syntax, android-intent

I'm learning Java and playing around with Android samples in Eclipse. I've come across code from two different sources and would like to know the difference between the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
```

---AND---

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SomeActivity.class);
```

Thanks!

(All these objects make me feel like I'm building a puzzle rather than coding. Not having much fun here...:))

Comment: I think it is the same, the second is a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you create the `Intent` with the class data. In the second case you create an empty `Intent` and set the class data after. The result is the same, according to the [android source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/content/Intent.java).

The constructor:

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```

The `setClass` method:

```
public Intent setClass(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks kriz! Makes so much more sense looking at the code than the documentation!